# php format string to remove the 1st element

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to remove the 1st value from the below string, i want to remove 'Type' value only

> Post type..:Type
>
> Post type..:Articles
>
> Post type..:Artists & Makers
>
> Post type..:Videos
>
> Post type..:In The Press
>
> Post type..:Did You Know ?
>
> Post type..:Glossary A - Z
>
> Post type..:Events
>
> Post type..:Recent Catalogs

I tried converting the above into an array and tried removing the 1st entry which i tried like below.] or can it be done without converting them into array.

```
foreach($posttype as $post){
if(getCapitalLetters($post)){
    $array = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $post);   //converting them to array
    echo '<pre>';echo 'Post type..:';
    echo str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', substr($post,0,-2));
   
    }
}



function getCapitalLetters($str)
{
  if(preg_match_all('#([A-Z]+)#',$str,$matches))
  {
    //echo 'Matches';print_r($matches);
    return implode('',$matches[1]);
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What does your current code look like?

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Format your array in your question, this is unreadable and I wont format it myself to understand.  Then show your desired output, and code you have tried.

Comment: Have updated my question @Clive, need to format my string properly and get the value without quotes and remove anything after the quotes

Comment: Have formatted my array and question as well @Nic3500

Comment: What does your original, unmolested input look like? It's probably more worthwhile to ask for help parsing *that* rather than how to re-make steak from ground beef.

Comment: The original input is Array which i formatted and kept only these strings which i need to display in drop down

Comment: This question seems very complicated for what it is.  You want to extract the value between the double quotes?  Use this `$original = "Post type:\"Blog Post\";s"; $post = preg_replace('/.*\"(.+)\";s/','$1',$original);`.  Then $post will be `Blog Post`.

Comment: trim() will only delete from the beginning and end of the string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).  So if your string is `"af"eee` it will only remove the first double quote, since the second one is not at the end.

Comment: hi @Nic3500, i have simplified the question, i just need to remove the first element from the string, which i basically im trying to convert them into array , not sure if its right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from your last comment, I came up with this:

```
$posttype = 'Post type..:Type

Post type..:Articles

Post type..:Artists & Makers

Post type..:Videos

Post type..:In The Press

Post type..:Did You Know ?

Post type..:Glossary A - Z

Post type..:Events

Post type..:Recent Catalogs';

$posttypearray = preg_split('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/',$posttype,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($posttypearray);
echo "</pre>";

$cleanposttypearray = preg_replace('/.*\.\.:(.*)$/','$1',$posttypearray);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cleanposttypearray);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output of this code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Post type..:Type
    [1] => Post type..:Articles
    [2] => Post type..:Artists & Makers
    [3] => Post type..:Videos
    [4] => Post type..:In The Press
    [5] => Post type..:Did You Know ?
    [6] => Post type..:Glossary A - Z
    [7] => Post type..:Events
    [8] => Post type..:Recent Catalogs
)
Array
(
    [0] => Type
    [1] => Articles
    [2] => Artists & Makers
    [3] => Videos
    [4] => In The Press
    [5] => Did You Know ?
    [6] => Glossary A - Z
    [7] => Events
    [8] => Recent Catalogs
)
```

What is does:

- use `preg_split` with option **PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY**.  This cuts the line in an array and automatically flushes the empty array values (i.e. the empty lines in `$posttype`).
- then use `preg_replace` to keep only what follows `..:`.  `preg_replace` will apply the replacement you want on every element of an array for you.  No need to loop.

So that is how I transformed your input into an array of each type.